# SolverFactory.newDefault(); return in play framework project always null

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, linear-programming, scpsolver

I am working on an Play Framework project. The next step I wanted to do was to add the linear programming part of the project. Therefore I included the libraries from this website: http://scpsolver.org

And if I want to run the little example code in a little java program in IntelliJ, it just works fine. But if I add the same little code example to my Play Framework project, it crashes because the SolverFactory.newDefault() always returns null. And I don't know why.

This is the error I receive as soon as it hits the mention code line:

```
[NullPointerException: null]
In /Users/stefanroth/Desktop/Project Kopie/IDP_Benchmarking-master/target/scala-2.11/routes/main/router/Routes.scala:321
318    // @LINE:19
319    case controllers_Application_lpSimpleSolver7_route(params) =>
320      call { 
321        controllers_Application_lpSimpleSolver7_invoker.call(Application_2.lpSimpleSolver())
322      }
323  
324    // @LINE:21
325    case controllers_Application_jsRoutes8_route(params) =>
326      call {
```

And the line 321 is red highlighted.

Oh and this might be an important information. At the moment I am working on an Mac Sierra 10.12.4. I mention this, because before my windows laptop broke, I was working on it and it worked there without any problems, besides the need to work with the 32-bit JDK.

Comment: How did you include the libraries?

Comment: I put them into the lib folder of my project. But if it wouldn't find the libraries, it would already start complaining of not finding the imports right?

Comment: You're right. This sounds like you need to either initialize `controllers_Application_lpSimpleSolver7_invoker`, or `Application_2`.

Comment: I don't think so. Because on any windows computer the application works fine. Only on the macbook I receive this error for some reason. But maybe I actually do wrongly include the libs so it doesn't find this methods. But I wouldn't know how to do it else

Comment: Maybe this might help: `http://scpsolver.org/javadoc/scpsolver/lpsolver/SolverFactory.html#newDefault()` . It looks like there is no service provider of the LinearProgramSolver.

Comment: But then why does it work as soon as I run it on a windows pc?

Comment: Also btw. If I run the only the sample code from scpsolver.org in IntelliJ, it works fine and newDefault() doesn't return null.

Comment: Have you also included a solver pack alongside the `SCPSolver.jar` file?

Comment: Yes of course. But this might be interesting. If I run the little code example in IntelliJ, it works fine and SolverFactory.newDefault() doesn't return null. Only in the PlayFramework project this problem seems to be appearing. But I don't know whats causing it....